# Swift + CoreLocation not working

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, ios8

I am trying to get the users location using CLLocationManager. For some reason locationManager:didUpdateLocations is never called. Bellow is the code for the view controller.

Note: I have added the necessary keys to the info.plist and enabled location services in the simulator.

The console output is: "Location to Allowed"

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreLocation

    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
        var location_seenError: Bool = false
        var location_fixAchieved: B

ool = false
    var location_status: NSString = "Not Started"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        location_seenError = false;
        location_fixAchieved = false;
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    // Location Manager Delegate stuff
    // If failed
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        NSLog("locationManager:didFailWithError")
        if (error) {
            if (location_seenError == false) {
                location_seenError = true
                NSLog("Location Error")
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        NSLog("locationManager:didUpdateLocations")
        if (location_fixAchieved == false) {
            location_fixAchieved = true
            var locationArray = locations as NSArray
            var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation
            var coord = locationObj.coordinate

            NSLog("lat: \(coord.latitude)")
            NSLog("lon: \(coord.longitude)")
        }
    }

    // authorization status
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager,
        didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            var shouldIAllow = false

            switch status {
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
                location_status = "Restricted Access to location"
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
                location_status = "User denied access to location"
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
                location_status = "Status not determined"
            default:
                location_status = "Allowed to location Access"
                shouldIAllow = true
            }
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LabelHasbeenUpdated", object: nil)
            if (shouldIAllow == true) {
                NSLog("Location to Allowed")
                // Start location services
                manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
                locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            } else {
                NSLog("Denied access: \(location_status)")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simulator does not have GPS capabilities. However, you can simulate a GPS position with the GPS-Icon on the bottom of the debugger window. After choosing one of the positions there you should get a location update so `locationmanager.didUpdateLocations` should be called.

You cann add your own location to the list by adding a GPX file with a mappoint to your project.